# Laravel bash alias

Tags: bash, laravel, config, alias

I wanted to make my life a bit easier, so I have made a bash function that when called with a parameter creates a new Laravel project together with installing composer and some of the packages and so on and so forth.

Anyway, I was wondering if there is a way to update config/app.php via command line so that I don't have to edit providers and aliases manually?

Here is the script

```
function laranew(){
        laravel new $1;
        cd $1;
        composer install;
        composer require laravelcollective/html;
        php artisan key:generate;
        composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar;
        php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider";
}
```

Edit: as Fabio suggested, I have updated the script accordingly

```
function laranew(){
        laravel new $1;
        cd $1;
        composer install;
        composer require laravelcollective/html;
        php artisan key:generate;
        composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar;
        php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider";
        composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper;
        php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider" --tag=config;
        composer require doctrine/dbal;
        cp ~/Code/app.php ~/Code/$1/config/app.php;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a generic app.php with the providers you want by default and then just copy it to your project location?

Comment: That is actually a pretty smart solution. I was thinking about that before, but now it occurred to me that I can automate the copy process. I will update the post with the new script

Comment: I like the global bash script solution much more. Think about the nightmare to maintain the code if just get copied over to multiple locations.

Comment: What do you mean? It gets copied right where it needs to. I just need the starting boilerplate so I am not worried about maintenance because after creation of the project, the script does nothing... The code works as expected